# Is conceivability relative to the subject?

Tags: reference-request, concept

Is conceivability relative to the subject? By this, I mean, can some beings conceive more things, or different things, than other beings? Personally, I believe the answer is yes. I believe that, for instance, humans can conceive of more states of affairs than cats or chimpanzees. Also, I believe that some humans can conceive of different states of affairs than other humans. But what have professional philosophers written about this question?

Comment: This isn’t a philosophy question; it’s a psychological/scientific one that is hard to answer given that we can’t access other conscious experiences. I don’t think there’s anything that only a few humans can conceive of though. Conceivability of objects often is an image in your brain that I can’t see why others can’t access, atleast in principle.

Comment: Define "conceive" and you will not have to just "believe", your definition will determine the answer. For some definitional options considered in the literature see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/ENTRIES/zombies/#ConcArguForPossZomb). If "conceive" simply means positing a facially consistent set of propositions involving some concepts then the answer is no. But if it imposes some requirements on the depth/breadth of conception, say, then it will obviously depend on the subject's processing capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two related notions of conceivability, one psychological and one philosophical. In the psychological sense, a state of affairs is conceivable or not-conceivable by an individual. One person might be able to conceive something that another person cannot. Although you can't see whether someone is conceiving something, you can give various tests. For example, if you ask someone to conceive what it would be like to be living on Larry Niven's Ring World, you can test whether they are successful by asking them what they would see looking up into the sky. Naturally, people will differ in what they can conceive just like they differ in all other mental capacities.

However, in philosophy, the word is used a bit differently. When a philosopher says that some state of affairs is not conceivable, he doesn't mean that he can't conceive of it, he means that no human can conceive of it. He may be wrong about that, but that is what he generally means. The point of something being inconceivable in philosophy is the conviction that most of us feel that with enough effort we can conceive of (or imagine) anything that we could possibly experience, so if we cannot conceive of something we could not experience it.

We can conceive of the Ring World, so the Ring World something that we could possibly experience. This doesn't mean that the Ring World is physically possible, just that if it were physically possible, it's something that we could grasp and experience. Compare this to a state of affairs where two parallel lines intersect. That state of affairs is not conceivable, and if it were to happen, it's not clear how we could possibly experience it. If we experienced the state of affairs where two lines intersected, we would not at the same time judge them as parallel. It just doesn't seem possible.

There is room for disagreement on various issues, of course. On the more dogmatic side, some philosophers have argued that something that is inconceivable is metaphysically impossible. One might claim on that basis that two parallel lines necessarily never intersect. A Kantian might argue that although the inconceivable may not be metaphysically impossible, it is transcendentally impossible in the sense that a state of affairs that is inconceivable cannot be a part of the phenomenal world. On the more skeptical side, some philosophers might argue that although we can't conceive of a new color we have never seen before, yet when shown the color, we can experience it. If true this would cast doubt on the general idea that just because we cannot conceive of something we cannot experience it.